# If Err.Description = "...." Then ..... in VBscript

Tags: excel, vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

I'm fixing the bellow error "datatable importsheet operation failed. Invalid file" using this way:

```
On error resume next

DataTable.ImportSheet Environment("STPFilePath"),Environment("TestScriptName"),"Action2" 

If Err.Description = "The DataTable.ImportSheet operation failed. Invalid file." \n "Line (20): "DataTable.ImportSheet Environment("STPFilePath"),Environment("TestScriptName"),"Action2""."  Then

list of instructions

end if
```

But I got this error:

The test run cannot continue due to a syntax error.

```
Expected 'Then'

Line (24): "If Err.Description = "The DataTable.ImportSheet operation failed. Invalid file." \n "Line (20): "DataTable.ImportSheet Environment("STPFilePath"),Environment("TestScriptName"),"Action2""."  Then".
```

Everything looks right. Please any help ? where I'm wrong ?

Comment: Why would you do a comparison against `Err.Description`?, makes no sense use `Err.Number` instead.

Comment: `/n` means nothing in Basic. In C it means newline, but in Basic nothing. And we join strings with `&`.

Comment: @Noodles don't you mean `\n` not `/n`? - [Back Slash Vs Forward Skash](http://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~pconrad/topics/BackslashVsForwardSlash/)

Comment: I do. Now stuff to make 10 chars, so I can say *I do.*

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do, the error occurs because `DataTable.ImportSheet()` fails to load the file. Do you want to capture when this fails? If so first print the `Err.Number` to screen make a note of it then to check for it use `If Err.Number = ... Then` where `...` is the `Err.Number` you have made a note of, or simply use `If Err.Number <> 0 Then` to capture any error that occurs while running `DataTable.Importsheet()`.

Comment: I want to copy the script into another excel sheet automatically if the DataTable import sheet failed

Comment: In which case check for the `Invalid file` `Err.Number` value instead of trying to compare the returned `Err.Description`. You can find the value easily by outputting `Err.Number` and then adding the return value as your `If Err.Number = ... Then` check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm really struggling with what you are trying to do and your comments are not helping...

When using

```
On Error Resume Next
```

and you encounter an error while executing a statement the following things will happen;

1. The statement will be skipped and the script will move to the next statement and carry on execution.
2. The object `Err` will be populated with details of the error that caused the statement to be skipped.

The [`Err` object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbf5ze0e(v=vs.84).aspx) is made up of a few key properties that describe the error that occurred;

- `Number` - The Error Code of the error that was raised.
- `Source` - The Source of the error that was raised, this can be 3rd party library, the VBScript Runtime etc.
- `Description` - A free text description of the error.

If you want to check for error

> The DataTable.ImportSheet operation failed. Invalid file.

when

```
DataTable.ImportSheet Environment("STPFilePath"),Environment("TestScriptName"),"Action2"
```

is executed you need to capture the `Err.Number` code that corresponds to that specific error.

Something like this;

```
On Error Resume Next

DataTable.ImportSheet Environment("STPFilePath"),Environment("TestScriptName"),"Action2" 
'Check that an error occurs
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
  'Identify specific error and deal with accordingly.
  Select Case Err.Number
  Case 20012 'Code for DataTable.ImportSheet operation failed
    'List of instructions...
  Case Else
    'Unhandled error show to screen
    MsgBox "Error: " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Source & ") - " & Err.Description
  End Select
  'Finished handling the error
  Call Err.Clear()
End If
```

---

What I find most confusing is the miss-information in this thread.

- > *"I need the description and not the number and the problem is to use Err.Details and not Err.Description in my case. Now, it is working."* - [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39878005/if-err-description-then-in-vbscript/39893771#comment67071368_39886144)

  The `Err` object does not contain a property called `Details` unless this is something specific to QTP but so far I haven't been able to find anything with a quick Google Search. So how you can say *"it is now working"* is beyond me.

Comment: @sourh did you give this a try? How did you get on?

Comment: Thank you, I'm working now using your solution, it's working. I was using Err.description instead of  Err.Number because it's my first use of on Error resume next and I have an example using the description but using the error Number is better. Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

Basic rules:

1. Double Quotes (") are escaped by doubling ("")
2. No escapes like "\n" in VBScript string literals (concatenation (or replacement) needed)
3. The concatenation operator is &

Basic strategy: Simplify, Divide, and conquer:

```
>> s = "1" & vbCrLf & "-""pi""-"
>> t = "1" & vbCrLf & "-""pi""-"
>> WScript.Echo s
>> WScript.Echo t
>> If s = t Then
>>    WScript.Echo "no surprise"
>> End If
>>
1
-"pi"-
1
-"pi"-
no surprise
>>
```

**Added:**

Applied to your string/error message:

```
's = "The DataTable.ImportSheet operation failed. Invalid file." \n "Line (20): "DataTable.ImportSheet Environment("STPFilePath"),Environment("TestScriptName"),"Action2""."
 s = "1" & vbCrLf & "2: ""3(""4""),5(""6""),""7""."
 WScript.Echo s
```

output:

```
cscript 39878005.vbs
1
2: "3("4"),5("6"),"7".
```

Comment: my eyeballs don't like that your output (while correct) has an unterminated string... How very pedantic of me!

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a syntax error because the double quotes in your if statement are not escaped.

I'm not sure what you are trying to do here and maybe using Err.Number makes more sense but if you want to avoid the syntax error then use this code:

```
If Err.Description = "The DataTable.ImportSheet operation failed. Invalid file."" \n ""Line (20): ""DataTable.ImportSheet Environment(""STPFilePath""),Environment(""TestScriptName""),""Action2""." Then
    ''' list of instructions
End If
```

Also, you cannot use \n if you want to compare 2 lines in if statement. Use `CHR(13)` or `CHR(10)` instead of \n. I.e.

```
If Err.Description = "The DataTable.ImportSheet operation failed. Invalid file."& CHR(13) &"Line (20): ""DataTable.ImportSheet Environment(""STPFilePath""),Environment(""TestScriptName""),""Action2""." Then

'''list of instructions

End If
```

Again: Using Err.Number will make more sense as any extra/missing space/newline in above If condition will fail the condition.

Answer (score -1):

Try to Replace the Err.Description line with this

```
If Err.Description = "The DataTable.ImportSheet operation failed. Invalid file." & vbCrLf & "Line (20): DataTable.ImportSheet Environment(" & STPFilePath & "),Environment(" & TestScriptName & ")," & Action2 & "." Then
```

Good Luck.!

Comment: Why would you do this? I would cry if having to modify this code, just use the `Err.Number`.

Comment: I need the description and not the number and the problem is to use Err.Details and not Err.Description in my case. Now, it is working.

Comment: @sourh what?, that makes no sense, why do you need to check the description returned? plus I've never heard of `Err.Details` there is no such property of the `Err` object in VBScript.